# Find widget in Jupyter Notebook in VS Code gives inconsistent, high number of results

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, editor

I'm editing a Jupyter Notebook in visual studio code. I want to find every occurrence of "s11" in my code using ctrl + f. There should only be a handful of occurrences (maybe 5). But the search bar randomly switches from finding a total of 183 occurrences to 500 occurrences (shown in the screenshot below). I can search the same term over and over and get different results every time.

[image]

Another strange part is that the ctrl + f function works fine with other Jupyter Notebook documents. Any ideas what is issue might be and how to fix it?

*Extra details:*

**VS CODE Help, About command output**

- Version: 1.82.1 (system setup)
- Commit: 6509174151d557a81c9d0b5f8a5a1e9274db5585
- Date: 2023-09-08T08:45:05.575Z
- Electron: 25.8.0
- ElectronBuildId: 23503258
- Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
- Node.js: 18.15.0
- V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

**Python/Jupyter Versions used**

- Jupyter Extension Version: v2023.8.1002501831
- jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
- jupyter_core     : 4.11.1
- jupyter_server   : 1.18.1
- Python 3.9.14

Comment: are any of those in cell outputs? what if you open the file as json (use `View: Reopen Editor With...` in the command palette and then select "Text Editor")?

Comment: @starball Sometimes "s11" is in the cell outputs but not that many times. Some more context: the "find" function doesn't actually take me to specific places in the code. When I reopen editor with text editor, the find function works as normal. It consistently finds "s11" 399 times and highlights the place it occurs in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you observe consistent results with the text editor find widget when you open the notebook with the text editor using `View: Reopen Editor With...` in the command palette and then selecting "Text Editor", I suspect this to be a bug. I did a cursory google of "`github vscode jupyter OR notebook issues find occurrences`" to see if there were any existing issue tickets and looked at the first page of results and didn't see one. I think all that you can do now is just raise a bug ticket, which you can do using the `Help: Report Issue...` command in the command palette. The issue is either with the Jupyter extension or with VS Code's Notebook feature. The report issue procedure should lead you through an extension bisect which should help determine whether it's caused by the Jupyter extension or not (which will determine whether your issue ticket gets filed under the VS Code repo, or the Jupyter extension repo).

The link to the issue ticket raised by the asker is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194823. The ticket has been closed for not enough info and not responding to requests for more info. Take this as a cautionary tale to be responsive to maintainers. Raise a new issue ticket if you still have this problem.

Another issue ticket which might be related: [fail to display the total counts of search results in jupyter #198359](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/198359).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.